# how authorization asp(mvc) project from controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-authorization

I'm new in asp and I created a login page for my web project but and I set authentication but I can not set authorization for my project! I saw many links like this [Authentication and Authorization in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api)
but couldn't implementation those on my own project, I don't know where I must to start?!
thank you for your help!

this is my controller:

```
public class AuthenticationController : Controller
{
    private modelLayOut mLO = new modelLayOut();
    public bool existBool = false; 
    // GET: Authentication
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult applicantAuthentication()
    {            
        return View("ApplicantAuthentication");
    }
    public ActionResult applicantIsExist()
    {
        return View("applicantIsExist");
    }
    public ActionResult applicantPassIsWrong()
    {
        return View("applicantPassIsWrong");
    }
    public ActionResult applicantNotExist()
    {
        return View("applicantNotExist");
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult applicantCreate(string Username, string Password, string RepeatPassword)
    {
        if (mLO.applicantExistCheck(Username))
        {
            return View("applicantIsExist");
        }
        else
        {
            mLO.insertNewApplicant(Username, Password);
            return View("ApplicantAuthentication");
        }
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult applicantAccess(string Username, string Password)
    {
        if (mLO.applicantAccess(Username, Password))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Home", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            if (mLO.applicantExistCheck(Username))
            {
                return View("applicantPassIsWrong");
            }
            else
            {
                return View("applicantNotExist");
            }
        }
    }

    //agency part
    public ActionResult agencyAuthentication()
    {
        return View("AgencyAuthentication");
    }
    public ActionResult agencyPassIsWrong()
    {
        return View("agencyPassIsWrong");
    }
    public ActionResult agencyNotExist()
    {
        return View("agencyNotExist");
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult agencyAccess(string Username, string Password)
    {
        if (mLO.agencyAccess(Username, Password))
        {               
            return RedirectToAction("Home", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            if (mLO.agencyExistCheck(Username))
            {
                return View("agencyPassIsWrong");
            }
            else
            {
                return View("agencyNotExist");
            }
        }
    }

    //webAdmin
    public ActionResult webAdminAuthentication()
    {
        return View("WebAdminAuthentication");
    }
    public ActionResult webAdminAccessWrong()
    {
        return View("webAdminAccessWrong");
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult webAdminAccess(string Username, string Password)
    {
        if (mLO.webAdminAccess(Username, Password))
        {
            Session["Username"] = Username;
            return RedirectToAction("webAdminPage", "Admin");
        }
        else
        {
            return View("webAdminAccessWrong");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fully understand `ASP.NET 5 Identity model` (Check [here](http://johnatten.com/2013/11/11/extending-identity-accounts-and-implementing-role-based-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc-5/) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/727054/ASP-NET-MVC-Identity-Extending-and-Modifying-R)). Then you should implement that with any changes suits to your project. One of the most important things about `ASP.NET 5 Identity` is its simplicity and flexibility to use with different user types and accessibility with just using annotations for methods. If you have previous experience with `SQL Membership`, check [here](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity) to find out how to Migrating from SQL Membership to ASP.NET Identity. Or if you have previous experience with `ASP.NET Membership`, check [here](http://travis.io/blog/2015/03/24/migrate-from-aspnet-membership-to-aspnet-identity/) to find out how to Migrate from ASP.NET Membership to ASP.NET Identity. 
About your question on `how say: "welcome PERSON NAME" ?`, after implementation ASP.NET 5 Identity, you just need to have

> System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

in where ever you need!.

Answer (score 0):

If you want authorization on your whole controller, just set the Authorize attribute on your controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class AuthenticationController : Controller
{

}
```

If you want authorization on a sigle action:

```
public class AuthenticationController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome, " + HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Only authenticated users will be able to navigate through authorized methods or controllers

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! that thing I want to know is: how my project can set different between two guys that use my website in the same time?    just [Authorize] is enough? or I need add some thing! for example after login how say: "welcome PERSON NAME" ?

Comment: Everything about the authenticated user can be found at System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity object.

Comment: Hope this answer helps you