# How to Manage Two Kind of User with seprate Table in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2, owin-middleware

I'm working on project using ASP.Net MVC 5 that have two type of user Type1 and Type2 the username of each user Type is his phone number one person should be able to sign up as both Type1 and Type2 user it mean each type should have separate register form and so it seems each type should have separate Table to store.
And the problem is this how should I manage them for Authentication and Authorization system?
Should I Use ASP.NET Identity? with any solution?
Or Is there Any solution better than ASP.NET Identity

Comment: why you need two type of user ?? i guess you need two types of roles not user ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching i found a solution [here](https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Quick-and-Easy-ASPNET-Identity-Multitenancy)

Answer (score 1):

If you using `ASP.Net MVC 5` you should diffidently go to `ASP.NET Identity`.Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38133469/3743442) for more information about `ASP.NET Identity`. Then you should differentiate between `role` and `claim` clearly in your authentication implementation in `ASP.NET Identity` which suits to your project.